# IOS Google Analytics V2 session tracking

Tags: ios, session, google-analytics, tracker

I recently started to implement Google Analytics V2 beta in my app and i would like to know how can i track when it is launched. My code is:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 120;
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"ID"];

    self.tracker.sessionStart = YES;

    return YES;
}
```

I don't want to track it as an event. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try this:

```
[self.tracker trackView:@"App started"];
```